# Is there a javascript loader that supports using multiple versions of common libraries in the same browser window?

Tags: javascript, dependencies, amd, yui3

We have a system where multiple back-end services serve up front-end content that ultimately gets combined into a single web page.

Currently, we use the YUI3 loader to support javascript and css dependency management for YUI and other javascript libraries (e. g. jQuery, knockout).

What I'm wondering is, is there a way (using YUI3's loader or some other loader) for this process to be robust to having multiple versions of a library on a page?

For example, if all consuming code took the $ object as an argument rather than using the global $, then theoretically the loader could store a copy of $ version 1.1 and $ version 1.2 outside of global scope and pass these objects to the consuming code as appropriate.

Comment: do you have control over the back-end services? and do you want this only for jQuery? if answer to both of them is yes then you can use $.noConflict().

Comment: If the JS code was not written with multiple  versions in mind, what you are trying to do it basically impossible. Means changing all of those JS files to use different variables for $. How would $ for 1.1 know to use that instead of $ from 1.2?

Comment: @Shaunak: I want this to support a bunch of libraries, not just jQuery. That noConflict() function is interesting, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it and it might need some fine tuning but this is the way I think it can be done.

The YUI Loader allows loading multiple versions of YUI itself.  That is the reason that it provides the argument usually called `Y` to the callback it calls when it is done loading the requested modules:

```
YUI().use('moduleA', 'moduleB', ... , function (Y) {
```

You can call `YUI().use()` multiple times and each will deliver its own version of `Y` with the modules requested.

Moreover, you can nest calls to `use()`

```
YUI().use('moduleA', 'moduleB', ... , function (Y) {
     // ......
     Y.use('moduleC', function (X) {
```

For the second instance, I used `X` as the argument to the callback so you can actually use `X` where `'moduleC'` is available and `Y` where it isn't.  The other modules are available in both `X` and `Y`.  Or you can simply close one `YUI().use()` and start a separate one, each with its own modules (see: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/yui/yui-multi.html).

For external modules, please watch this video at about 42 minutes into it.  It shows how to load external modules and integrate them into that `Y` or `X` or whatever you want to call it.  In the callback to the `onProgress` event, the loaded module gets added into the YUI instance, that is `Y`, by calling `YUI.add()`.  The `Y` argument provided to the callback of `YUI.add()` is the same one you will get in the callback for `YUI().use()`.

So, it is a matter of defining the external modules giving each one, each version or whatever, a different module name, each pointing to the corresponding path for that version.  The `base` configuration in the `groups` configuration attribute (see: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/yui/loader.html#example-config) can be handy if each version shares a common root path.

Two gotchas I can think of.  First, if the external library loads everything into a global variable, there would be remnants of whatever got loaded first when you load the second version.  If that creates conflicts, you might have to delete that global object after a reference to it was put into `Y`.  This should be done after the whole batch of modules is loaded, possibly in the `onSuccess` callback, not in the `onProgress` callback since otherwise you would be erasing the dependencies of later modules.

The second is kind of remote and too long to explain.  Since it might not happen at all, lets leave it for later.